# Uniform convergence of Lipschitz functions to characteristic function of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions

Consider $(X,d)$ a metric space and $K \subseteq X$ a compact subset.
I am trying to build a sequence of Lipschitz functions $f_n : X \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f_n \to \chi_K$ uniformly.

If we try to build
$$ f_n(x) := 1 - \max \{n d(x,K), 1 \} ,$$
we don't have uniform convergence because we have problems just outside the boundary of $K$ (more specifically, we can find $x \not \in K $ s.t. $d(x,K)$ is arbitrarily small, thus $ \sup _n \sup_{x \not \in K} |1 - \max \{ n d(x,K), 1 \} | = 1$).

Is there some sequence of Lipschitz functions which converges uniformly to $\chi_K$, or does the kind of behaviour outlined before always happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_n$ converge uniformly, then the limit (in this case $\chi_K$) will be continuous. In most cases, this is false (for example for $K \neq \emptyset$ and $X = \Bbb{R}^n$).

To see this, note that (by the intermediate value theorem) $\chi_K$ would have to attain the value $1/2$ if it was continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is always continuous, so this will only work if the characteristic function of the compact set is continuous itself. However, this is in general not the case.

I assume you try to find such a sequence in order to prove something related to measure theory. It is probably not necessary to have uniform convergence, so it might be the best if you start a new question stating your original problem.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to approximate the characteristic function of a compact set with Lipschitz functions in $L^p(m), \forall p \in [1, \infty]$ and for $m$ a finite measure. For $p < \infty$ I manage to prove it using the $f_n$ as above and dominated convergence. Then I was wondering if the statement was true even for $p = \infty$.

Comment: @quia: No, in general it is not. To see this, note that for the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^n$, the $L^\infty$ norm coincides with the usual sup norm **on continuous functions**. Thus, if $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty$, then $(f_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $L^\infty$ and then with respect to the sup norm. Hence, $f_n \to g$ uniformly for some continuous function $g$. Hence, $\chi_K =f=g$ almost everywhere. But there are compact sets for which this cannot hold.